# GAE custom domain but with SMTP control

Tags: google-app-engine, email, dns, google-apps, google-compute-engine

I understand that in order to link my domain to my GAE application I need to setup Google Apps according to [this](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/domain).

But Google Apps seems to take control of SMTP and email addresses. I need to have my own SMTP server in GCS, which is working perfectly right now using the static ip like someuser@xx.xx.xx.xx

What I need is to be able to enter my GAE web application thru mydomain.com but at the same time being able to receive anyuser@mydomain.com at my SMTP instance at GCS. Is it possible?

Comment: Probably in this case is safe to skip mail-related DNS registers. Google Apps is does more than support GAE, and probably you don't need this additional functionality.

Comment: Xavier: you are saying that I can skip using Google Apps or that I can use Google Apps and skip its mail related functionality not modifying some DNS registers?

Comment: The second approach, not modifying DNS registers should do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your email settings are determined by your registrar, not by Google Apps. If you don't want to use Gmail as your mail server, you simply keep your DNS records unchanged, as Xavier correctly suggested.